# Base10 encryption for a String

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to find a way to obtain a base10 value for a String. This is easily achievable with the hash code function as shown. But I've noticed the values turns up sequential or close to it. Example below.

I am not dealing with a secure password or anything here, just wanting to be able to convert a String to base10 value and always get the same value when I do that.

May be bit over kill but looked at existing hashing options such as MessageDigest. But they are all Base64 (more or less) but none for Base10 which is expected considering that is not secure to begin with.

One possible option I am thinking is to use MessageDigest, get a base64 value and regex it to only extract out all the numbers. Meaning every time I encode via message digest and regex to get only Base10 values, I should always get same value.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? Instead of complicating it with encryptions which is not really needed in my case.

I just want to convert example as follows:

```
String s1 = "Sample00000000001";
// after encoding, getting Base10 value like -> 8725342728354

String s2 = "Sample00000000002"; 
// after encoding, getting Base10 value like -> 11576232138652 (random, not sequential even though only 1 character changed).
```

Trying with Base64 from Java Util which produces results in sequence (or close) thus not what I want. Will still need to regex out the Base10 values from here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String salt = "Sample";
    String num = "00000000001";
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    String value  = salt + num;
    String encoded = encoder.encodeToString(value.getBytes());
    String decoded = new String(decoder.decode(encoded));
    // 00000000001 gives U2FtcGxlMDAwMDAwMDAwMDE=
    // 00000000002 gives U2FtcGxlMDAwMDAwMDAwMDI=
}
```

Using hashcode which again ends up sequential or close

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String salt = "Sample";
    String num = "00000000002";

    String v = salt+num;
    int hash = v.hashCode();
    System.out.println(hash);
}
```

Last option I am looking at, using libraries like Bouncy castle or in built MessageDigest.

Assuming the encoding is done and I have assigned that to variable 'value' below. I could pull out only Base10 values from it via regex as follows.

```
String value = "HASDJHSDGF3423HIHGH234565BJB666";
long result =  Long.valueOf(value.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
System.out.println(result); // end up with 3423234565666 as expected.
```

I am currently leaning towards this last option to possibly use MessageDigest but looking for advice / options for a better way to do this. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what your goal here is.  Is this supposed to be reversible?  Why are sequential values bad?  What is the purpose of this number?

Comment: Base 64 similarity makes sense as it is just a way of representing the bytes in a minimal number of characters so a small change in string would just change a small number of bytes. To achieve the kind of randomness you are looking for does suggest maybe using a very simple encryption algorithm - they will usually output a byte array so you could just take the base 10 integer value of each byte and add together.

Comment: Or like you say, a digest would be easier, if security is no concern then just MD5 would do it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't plan to reverse it but after whatever hashing method I go for, I always want to get same hashed value for a particular String value. In terms of purpose, we are using the hashed value for some internal decision mechanisms. It can't be sequential.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with it being sequential?  If it were sequential in the reversed bits -- e.g. `Integer.reverse(string.hashCode())` -- would that suffice?

Comment: So no answer from me because it sounds like digest is best approach, which is the conclusion you have reached but easier to interpret bytes as numbers rather than treating as base 64 or hex string and extracting digits.

Comment: @LouisWasserman One of the rules in place is that last 2 digits in hash ending with 50 and below do something, otherwise do something else. It's coming from a list of some ids in the millions. We can't be having it in sequence. Sorry if this is not very clear but the underlying info is that it can't be in sequence and reverse() is not gonna help either.

Comment: If you do not want cryptographic security, then [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) is a lot simpler to code and comes in a variety of sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the message digest to generate an array of bytes and then read them as integer:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String salt = "Sample";
        String num = "00000000002";
        String num2 = "00000000001";

        hash(salt, num);
        hash(salt, num2);
    }

    private static void hash(String salt, String num) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            digest.reset();
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(digest.digest((num + digest).getBytes()));
            System.out.println(bytes.asIntBuffer().get());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or you can use the `Random` class (same seed produce the same "random" value) (I'm not sure from a performance point of view about the implications)

```java
   private static void hash(String salt, String num) {
        System.out.println(new Random(num.hashCode() + salt.hashCode()).nextInt());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of method `hashCode` is for searching objects in data structures such as HashMap. Standard implementation is based on address in memory, not content of a string, so for your case it is useless.

Base64 is not an encryption and also not a hash function. It only converts binary data so it can be stored as text, so small changes in input will make small changes in output.

What you need is to use some real hash function like SHA and convert result for your format.